# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key: python replacing DF1's column with DF2

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have two dataframes.
One dataframe one first, dataframe two second.

I want to replace country value based on DF 2.

| Code | Country | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NULL | foo | mei |
| 200 | NULL | bar | tes |
| 100 | NULL | foo1 | mei1 |
| 200 | NULL | bar1 | tes1 |
| 100 | NULL | foo2 | mei2 |
| 200 | NULL | bar2 | tes2 |

| Code | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Canada |
| 200 | USA |

Tried:

```
df1['Country'] = df2.replace(df1['Code'],df1['Country']
```

But this is throwing error: Columns must be same length as key

| Code | Country | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Canada | foo | mei |
| 200 | USA | bar | tes |
| 100 | Canada | foo1 | mei1 |
| 200 | USA | bar1 | tes1 |
| 100 | Canada | foo2 | mei2 |
| 200 | USA | bar2 | tes2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the replace method but a join.

```
import pandas as pd

code = [100, 200, 100, 200]
df1 =  pd.DataFrame(code, columns=['code'])
df1["country"] = None

df1.head()

# return
code    country
100     None
200     None
100     None
200     None


code2 = [100, 200]
coutry2 = ["Canada", "USA"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(code2, coutry2)), columns=['code', 'country'])
df2.head()
# output
code    country
100     Canada
200     USA


resutls = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='code', how='left')
resutls.head()

# output
 code   country_x   country_y
100     None        Canada
200     None        USA
100     None        Canada
200     None        USA

results_clean = resutls[['code', 'country_y']]
results_clean.columns = ['code', 'country']
results_clean.head()

code    country
100     Canada
200     USA
100     Canada
200     USA
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Did thought of using join and dropping and arranging columns, but SO was filled with replace.

Column C/D dropped. I can add them back, but i have like 20 columns. Is there a way to retain columns instead of retyping every?

Comment: you can retain all columns without problems, just need to drop "countr_x" and rename "country_y" for "country"