# replace the empty value in the dataframe with a list of python values

Tags: python, pandas

There is a list of shops
|Shop ID|
|-------|
| Shop1 |
| Shop2 |
| Shop3 |
There is a list of events that took place in the store
|Shop ID| Event   | Start_date | End_date  |
|-------|---------|------------|-----------|
| Shop1 | Action  | 01/01/2022 |05/01/2022 |
| Shop2 | Action  | 05/01/2022 |10/01/2022 |
|       | Action  | 15/01/2022 |20/01/2022 |
| Shop3 | Action  | 20/01/2022 |25/01/2022 |
If the Shop ID value is empty, it means that the event was held in all stores.
The following table must be displayed
|Shop ID| Event   | Start_date | End_date  |
|-------|---------|------------|-----------|
| Shop1 | Action  | 01/01/2022 |05/01/2022 |
| Shop2 | Action  | 05/01/2022 |10/01/2022 |
| Shop1 | Action  | 15/01/2022 |20/01/2022 |
| Shop2 | Action  | 15/01/2022 |20/01/2022 |
| Shop3 | Action  | 15/01/2022 |20/01/2022 |
| Shop3 | Action  | 20/01/2022 |25/01/2022 |

Comment: use a join like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696757/valueerror-columns-must-be-same-length-as-key-python-replacing-df1s-column-wi/71697715#71697715

Comment: Please keep your example as short as possible. You could remove `Shop4` and `Shop5` and question would still be valid.

Comment: What is in your empty cell? A NaN or an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You can fill the empty value with list then explode

```py
lst = ['Shop1','Shop2','Shop3','Shop4','Shop5']
df['Shop ID'] = df['Shop ID'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) else lst)
# or if your empty means NaN
df['Shop ID'] = df['Shop ID'].apply(lambda x: x if x != x else lst)
df = df.explode(['Shop ID'])
```

```
print(df)

  Shop ID   Event  Start_date    End_date
0   Shop1  Action  01/01/2022  05/01/2022
1   Shop2  Action  05/01/2022  10/01/2022
2   Shop1  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop2  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop3  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop4  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop5  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
3   Shop3  Action  20/01/2022  25/01/2022
4   Shop4  Action  25/01/2022  30/01/2022
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @AndriiKrush It seems NaN, you can try the second line or use `df['Shop ID'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x if len(x) else lst)`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @AndriiKrush What have you tried?

Comment: df['Shop ID'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x if len(x) else lst)

Comment: action['Shop ID'] = action['Shop ID'].fillna("").apply(lambda x: x if len(x) else lst)
action['Shop ID'] = action['Shop ID'].apply(lambda x: x if x != x else lst)
action = action.explode(['Shop ID'])

Comment: @AndriiKrush Note the meaning of `or`, you only need one `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

For a fully vectorial solution, you can use:

```
# unique (non-NA) IDs 
# NB. If your empty cells are empty string, convert to NaN first
IDs = df['Shop ID'].dropna().unique()

# identify NaNs
m = df['Shop ID'].isna()

# repeat NaNs
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(m.mul(len(IDs)-1).add(1))]

# replace with all shop IDs
df2.loc[m[m].index, 'Shop ID'] = np.repeat(IDs, m.sum())

print(df2)
```

output:

```
  Shop ID   Event  Start_date    End_date
0   Shop1  Action  01/01/2022  05/01/2022
1   Shop2  Action  05/01/2022  10/01/2022
2   Shop1  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop2  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop3  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
2   Shop4  Action  15/01/2022  20/01/2022
3   Shop3  Action  20/01/2022  25/01/2022
4   Shop4  Action  25/01/2022  30/01/2022
```